# XCode is very slow to suggest autocompletion

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

When I code in Xcode on my MacBook Pro at work, autosuggestions seem to take 6-8 seconds. On my MacBook Air at home, they appear instantly.

Is there any reason for this? I don't see anything in Xcode's preferences that would cause this:
[image: Xcode Preferences screengrab]

Any ideas here?

Comment: It's a brand-new MacBook Pro --- just got it about a month ago.

Comment: after Xcode completes its indexing, then also it is taking time?

Comment: Try repairing your disk permissions via disk utility if you haven't already.  I suppose it's possible that incorrect permissions on cache files could deny access to the static code analysis algorithms.

Comment: The reason why your MB Air is showing suggestions much faster is because of the SSD drive. However, taking 6 seconds is somewhat unusual for a new computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a shiny new iMac at work for development.  It's an i7 proc, 8 GB memory. Indexing (and the things that go with it, like code sense or quick documentation) was taking a very long time (5 minutes for ~600 files).  So was compilation.

The culprit turned out to be the corporate antivirus' on-access scan.  I disabled on-access scanning and indexing dropped to around 5 seconds for the same number of files.  Might be worth a shot if you have permissions to change antivirus settings.

Answer (score 3):

On one of the developer blogs I follow (I can't find the link at the moment), the author said he regularly has to delete the DerivedData folder for his projects because of corruption that causes issues like this. Give that a try and see if it helps.

It's not SSD vs. non-SSD. My 2009 MacBook Pro shows suggestions nearly instantaneously.

Comment: No luck! It's back to being unresponsive. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Now the responsiveness is back --- sorry for going back and forth on this. I have zero clue what's going on, but I've been told that your comment is likely what's helping. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully WWDC will bring an Xcode update. Version 4 still seems a bit half-baked.